# WCF 4.0 - How to route old service URL to new service URL?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, url-routing

I have an old WCF 3.5 RESTful service that was at:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/rest/Service.svc
```

I have migrated my service over to a WCF 4.0 RESTful service that now resides at:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/rest/Service
```

Due to the new WCF 4.0 routing in the Global.asax, it automatically removes the .svc extension for me. I was looking for a way to route the old base URL to the new base URL. I need to take into account that there will obviously be more after the Service name such as

```
Service.svc/MyEndpoint?param1=param1Val
```

Is this possible and if so, what is the best/most performant way to accomplish this task?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have both .svc file and the route-based activation, for *the same service class*, so the requests for both addresses would cause the service to be invoked. The endpoint from the .svc would be defined either using the Factory attribute on the <%@ ServiceHost %> directive or via web.config, and the endpoint from the route (svc-less) would be defined using the factory registered with the ServiceRoute.

Comment: Since I was using the WCF REST Service Template, this did not create the .svc file with the markup. I had to delete my class, create a new service, add the factory to the markup and wire it up in my Global.asax. I did not have to modify my web.config at all for this change. It worked out of the box.